# Including two graphics, first is depicted instead of second

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to integrate two different graphics into my document. The first one works like this:

```
some text...
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \includegraphics[natwidth=538,natheight=540, scale=0.5]{../gfx/pic1}
 \caption{someCaption \cite{pic1}}
\end{figure}
some text...
```

When I try to add another picture later in my document like this:

```
some text...
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \includegraphics[natwidth=621,natheight=167, scale=0.5]{../gfx/pic2}
 \caption{someCaption2 \cite{pic2}}
\end{figure}
some text...
```

Then the first picture is depicted twice (one time in its right location and a second time where the second pic should be) and the second picture is not displayed at all. What could be the cause for that? (This is my first document with `LaTeX`)

**EDIT**

It should look like

```
some text some text some text some text 
PIC A
some text some text some text some text
PIC B
some text some text some text some text
```

But it looks like

```
some text some text some text some text 
PIC A
some text some text some text some text 
PIC A
some text some text some text some text
```

Comment: Its not that it is not displayed in the place it should, but the first is depicted, where the second one should be though I included it separatly.

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: Then post a compilable document, not just fragments, please!

Comment: I can't, I don't even know the basics of latex... I just included the IEEE template for technical reports, as I need to use it. The only thing I can post is the code fragments I just posted, as it crashes there.

Comment: Anyway, the `\cite{...}` stuff is wrong

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: Well, it makes a correct reference to the bib file, my professor told me to do so..

Comment: You're citing an `image` file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: yes, to tell the source, where I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the two setups -- it depends somewhat on the image size, of course.

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\section{A section}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \includegraphics[natwidth=538,natheight=540, scale=0.5]{beeduck}
 \caption{someCaption} \label{pic1}%
\end{figure}

\blindtext


\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \includegraphics[natwidth=538,natheight=540, scale=0.5]{rapsfeld}
 \caption{someCaption2} \label{pic2}%
\end{figure}

% Non floating images. 
\section{Another section}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[natwidth=538,natheight=540, scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\captionof{figure}{someCaption3} \label{pic3}%
\end{center}

\blindtext
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[natwidth=538,natheight=540, scale=0.5]{rapsfeld}
\captionof{figure}{someCaption4} \label{pic4}%
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is this `\blindtext`?

Comment: @DoRe: Dummy text, just for filling purposes (basically). It's removed in a real production run